# build from custom git repo

Tags: git, ssh, docker-compose

`docker build git@some.url.de:/path/to/repo.git` works, but this compose file:

```
services: 
  servicea:
    build: git@some.url.de:/path/to/repo.git
```

yields

```
ERROR: error fetching: Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
: exit status 128
```

Git uses ssh to access the remote repo. I works from the cli, but not with compose, what's the catch here?

Answer (score 0):

You can set GIT_SSH_COMMAND to ssh -v

```
export GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -v'
```

That way, you will see the difference between the two commands (`docker build` and `docker-compose build`).
Typically, make sure they are executed by the same account (in order to benefit from the same `~/.ssh/known-hosts`)